# GitHub search: exact matches

Tags: github

Let's say I want to search through the PRs on my repo. I have two branches, "branch-abc" and "branch-abcdef"

If I do this search:

```
base:branch-abc
```

I will get all PRs of *both* branches, because "branch-abc" is contained in both names.

However, I want one and only one of the branches. How can I do this in a general way? That is to say, I could explicitly exclude "branch-abcdef" in this particular case, but I want to be agnostic to the branch names and just want to match on exact name, rather than a "contains" as GitHub is apparently doing.